# different number of available security updates in apt-check and unattend-upgrades script

Tags: apt, package-management, unattended-upgrades

I found that there is difference beetween number of security updates in `check_apt` and `unattended-upgrade scripts`.

Common `/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check` script uses `isSecurityUpgrade(ver)` function at line 40 to determine the status of package. And it seems that it work normally. It is simple to understand by reading a function code.

There is a result of `check_apt`:

```
root@pandora:/home/sysadmin# /usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --human-readable
125 packages can be updated.
4 updates are security updates.
```

But `unattended-upgrade` does not include this packages for upgrade.

```
root@pandora:/home/sysadmin# unattended-upgrade --dry-run -v
Initial blacklisted packages: 
Starting unattended upgrades script
Allowed origins are: ['o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security', 'o=trusty,a=nginx']
Option --dry-run given, *not* performing real actions
Packages that will be upgraded: 
Packages that are auto removed: ''
Packages auto-removed
```

I found them manually(by adding custom debug output to this scripts).

It is following packages:

```
liboxideqt-qmlplugin:amd64/trusty-security 1.9.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 upgradeable to 1.17.7-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
liboxideqtcore0:amd64/trusty-security 1.9.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 upgradeable to 1.17.7-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
liboxideqtquick0:amd64/trusty-security 1.9.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 upgradeable to 1.17.7-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
oxideqt-codecs-extra:amd64/trusty-security 1.9.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 upgradeable to 1.17.7-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
```

There is my settings of allowed origins:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
#  "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}";
  "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
  "${distro_codename}:nginx";
};
```

One more remark:

If we uncomment origin `"${distro_id}:${distro_codename}"`, these updates will be installed by `unattended-upgrade` script:

```
root@pandora:/home/sysadmin# unattended-upgrade --dry-run -v
Initial blacklisted packages: 
Starting unattended upgrades script
Allowed origins are: ['o=Ubuntu,a=trusty', 'o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security', 'o=trusty,a=nginx']
Option --dry-run given, *not* performing real actions
Packages that will be upgraded: liboxideqt-qmlplugin liboxideqtcore0 liboxideqtquick0 libsmbclient libwbclient0 oxideqt-codecs-extra python-samba samba samba-common samba-common-bin samba-dsdb-modules samba-libs samba-vfs-modules smbclient
```

Why this happens ?

UPDATE 1:

i found that this packages is added to `pkgs_kept_back` in `check_changes_for_sanity` in `/usr/bin/unattended-upgrade`

there is some code:

```
if check_changes_for_sanity(cache, allowed_origins,
                                            blacklisted_pkgs):
                # add to packages to upgrade
                pkgs_to_upgrade.append(pkg)
            ...
            else:
                logging.debug("sanity check failed")
                rewind_cache(cache, pkgs_to_upgrade)
                pkgs_kept_back.append(pkg.name)
```

Why this happens ?